# MySQL upgrade from 5.6 to 5.7 using the Windows ZIP archive distribution

Tags: mysql, database, upgrade

Currently MySQL is 5.6.50.0 need to upgrade it to 5.7.31

1. Stopped MySQL 5.6 service
2. extracted all files from mysql-5.7.31-winx64 into C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6 folder
3. started MySQL 5.6 service back again
4. ran mysql_upgrade in command prompt as administrator

output:
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Error: Server version (5.6.50-log) does not match with the version of
the server (5.7.31) with which this program was built/distributed. You can
use --skip-version-check to skip this check.

Then tried it with skip version :-
output:
mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1726: Storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support system tables. [mysql.plugin]

I do not know where I am doing wrong , Its exactly as per the steps mentioned in mysql documentation.

Comment: there is a lot more to it consult the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)

Comment: It looks like you are running the mysql_upgrade from 5.6.

Comment: I am not a dba , so all these steps in manual was too much for me. I uninstall 5.6 , without uninstalling data directory. Installed 5.7 using installer then imported the dump to 5.7. This worked for me I had only one database.